# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range 32 in loop

Tags: java, for-loop, substring

This error is hard to debug. It also isn't happening regularly. Can anybody help, please?  Is it possible the `substring` method is broken?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 32
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1765)
        at mmk.basej.main(basej.java:186)

Error in line: "tmp1 = filePathShort1.substring(0, 10)"
```

Here is my code:

```
            String tmp = null;              
            String pdf_name = null;
            for (int z = 0; z < list_chek.length; z++) {                
                if (list_chek[z].toString().indexOf("pdf") > 0 | list_chek[z].toString().indexOf("tif") > 0 | list_chek[z].toString().indexOf("jpg") > 0) {
                    String filePath1 = new String();
                    String filePathShort1 = new String();
                    String tmp1 = null;
                    filePath1 = dir + list_chek[z].toString();
                    filePathShort1 = list_chek[z].toString();
                    tmp1 = filePathShort1.substring(0, 10)
                            + filePathShort1.substring(20, filePathShort.indexOf("tsd7")-1)
                            + "_"
                            + filePath1.substring(
                                    filePath1.indexOf("tsd7"), filePath1
                                            .length() - 4);

                    if (name_no_time.equals(tmp1)) {
                        //System.out.println(name_no_time+" ----   "+tmp1);
                        System.out.println("PDF_NAME " + list_chek[z].toString());
                        pdf_name = list_chek[z].toString();
                    }
                    else if ((list_chek[z].toString().indexOf("jpg") > 0) && ((name_no_time + "_1").equals(tmp1))) { 
                        System.out.println("JPG_NAME " + list_chek[z].toString());
                        pdf_name = list_chek[z].toString();
                    }               
                }
            }
```

Comment: StringIndexOutOfBounds is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: Also, I think it's not possible that `tmp1 = filePathShort1.substring(0, 10)` is responsible of your error since, from [Java API documentation StringIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) _Thrown by String methods to indicate that an index is either negative or greater than the size of the string. For some methods such as the charAt method, this exception also is thrown when the index is equal to the size of the string._. Your error is most likely due to another line in your code.

Comment: It's something about tmp1 calculation. tmp1 =   2017-02-02005002801AFAC_tsd7 and filePathShort1 = 2017-02-02_15-32-46_005002801AFAC_tsd7.pdf

Answer (score 0):

```
filePathShort1 = list_chek[z].toString();
tmp1 = filePathShort1.substring(0, 10)
```

if list_chek[z].toString has a length < 10, then `substring(0, 10)` is longer than the supplied String. This is where your index out of bounds comes from. It's trying to reference and element beyond the bounds of the `tmp1`.
You'll get the same problem in the next line if the list_chek[z] < 20. you need to be checking your string length before calling the substring.

Comment: So if `filePathShort1 = 2017-02-02_15-32-46_005002801AFAC_tsd7.pdf` and tmp1 must be like: `2017-02-02005002801AFAC_tsd7` I must use `tmp1 = filePathShort1.substring(0, 9)` instead?

Comment: Strings have fixed size: `filePathShort1 = 2017-02-02_15-32-46_005002801AFAC_tsd7.pdf` and `tmp1=2017-02-02005002801AFAC_tsd7`

Comment: Are you sure they're all the same length and long enough? You may want to stick a debug statement in to check. The fact that it works sometimes and not others, and fails on that line with that Exception is a strong indicator that they're not all long enough.

Comment: A few other things:
`|` is a binary `or`, i think you want the logical one, `||`
You could also substitute `.contains("pdf")` for `.indexOf("pdf") > 0`

Comment: Strings are long enough. I had this error only with big file lists. Then I split that list on little portions and program is working fine on them.